# How to get the text of a textbox after setting the value using javascript calendar in c#?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a asp:TextBox control and a javascript calendar function associated with it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:11px;"></asp:TextBox>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onmouseover="if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);window.status='Show Calendar';return true;" onmouseout="if (timeoutDelay) calendarTimeout();window.status='';" onclick="g_Calendar.show(event,'formAddCosting.txtFromDate',false); return false;">
<img src="Images/calendar.gif" name="calendarFromDate" width="34" border="0" alt="" /></a>
```

I can select the date from javascript calendar and display it in the textbox. But when I try to check the date of the textbox for validation in code behind, the `dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.ToString());` shows `""` during debug. How do I get the value of the textbox from code behind? I am using VB2005, ASP.Net2.0 and C#.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I am doing it by using **sFromDate = Request.Form["txtFromDate"].ToString();** here, sFromDate is a string variable. But I'm not sure, why do I need to use **Request.Form** as the textbox is already a server control? By the way, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, One more thing (not related to the question), how do you mark the code lines in comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `TextBox` is readonly: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33649/ViewState-and-Readonly-Property-of-Textbox

So either enable and validate it (if user wants to enter date manually) or use a `HiddenField` instead to store the date from the calendar.

I would recommend the first option since it's always better not to treat the user like a child.

Answer (score 2):

Take following steps to get value from TextBox:

1. Remove `ReadOnly="false"` attribute from your text box as this the only reason you are not able to get the value of your textbox. The reason for this is that the value of your texytbox is not persisted in viewstate when using ReadOnly="true" or Enabled="false".
2. To make textbox readonly in code behind file in age load function write following code:

   txtFromDate.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");